# gradle : java tests ran twice

Tags: testing, gradle, intellij-idea, junit5

I am making a skeletton of a java project; the gradle build file has an annoying problem : tests are ran twice, one time by the task 'JUnitPlatformTest' and a second time by the task 'test'.

The first one seems to trigger the second, so I can't disable it, and I would like to keep the second one as there is a little difference between them : the first one is in the console (of intelliJ) and the second uses the integrated intelliJ window.

here is gradle.build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.3'
        classpath group: 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins', name: 'javafx-gradle-plugin', version: '8.8.2'
        classpath 'eu.appsatori:gradle-fatjar-plugin:0.3'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j' version '2.4.4'
}

apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
apply plugin: 'javafx-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'eu.appsatori.fatjar'

junitPlatform {
    platformVersion '1.0.3'
    reportsDir file('build/test-results/junit-platform')
    enableStandardTestTask true
    //show results summary even on success.
    details details.SUMMARY
    filters {
        tags {
            // Framework tests need to be run only when required to verify that this framework is still working.
            exclude "Framework"
        }
        includeClassNamePatterns '.*Test', '.*Tests'
    }
}



group 'lorry'
version '1'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
//mainClassName="imports.ColorfulCircles"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    def final junitVersion = "5.2.0"
    compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version: '4.1.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'
    compile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: junitVersion
    //compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.11.0'
    compile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: '3.9.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.7'

    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-params', version: junitVersion
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.7.22'

    testRuntime group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: junitVersion

    compile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'

    testCompile "org.testfx:testfx-core:4.0.13-alpha"
    testCompile 'org.testfx:testfx-junit5:4.0.13-alpha'
    testRuntime 'org.testfx:openjfx-monocle:8u60-b27'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    jvmArgs = [
            "-Dtestfx.robot=glass",
            "-Dtestfx.headless=true",
            "-Dprism.order=sw",
            "-Dprism.text=t2k",
            "-Dheadless.geometry=1920x1200-32"
    ]
}

test.dependsOn 'clean'

jfx {
    // minimal requirement for jfxJar-task
    mainClass = 'imports.ColorfulCircles'

    // minimal requirement for jfxNative-task
    vendor = 'lolveley'
}

jar {
    baseName = 'executable3'
    version =  ''
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                'Main-Class': 'imports.ColorfulCircles'
        )
    }
}
launch4j {
    outfile='bibliotek-v3.exe'
    mainClassName = 'imports.ColorfulCircles'
    icon = "${projectDir}\\icons\\hands2.ico"
    copyConfigurable = project.tasks.fatJar.outputs.files
    jar = "lib/${project.tasks.fatJar.archiveName}"
    //headerType = "console"
    //jar = "${buildDir}\\productFatJar\\fat.jar"
}

junitPlatformTest {
        jvmArgs = [
                "-Dtestfx.robot=glass",
                "-Dtestfx.headless=true",
                "-Dprism.order=sw",
                "-Dprism.text=t2k",
                "-Dheadless.geometry=1920x1200-32"
        ]
    }
```

and here is the result:

```
Testing started at 19:25 ...
19:25:01: Executing task 'test'...

> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes
> Task :clean
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :junitPlatformTest
constructeur appelÃ©
Before all
Before each
my test 1
Before each
my test 2
This test method should be run
Test run finished after 3630 ms
[         4 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         4 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         4 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         7 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         7 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         7 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
> Task :test
constructeur appelÃ©
Before all
Before each
my test 1
Before each
my test 2
This test method should be run
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 13s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
19:25:15: Task execution finished 'test'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this official website](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle), ...

> The JUnit Platform Gradle Plugin is deprecated
>
> The very basic `junit-platform-gradle-plugin` developed by the JUnit team was deprecated in JUnit Platform 1.2 and will be discontinued in 1.3. Please switch to Gradle’s standard test task.

So you should remove this plugin from your build file and, if necessary, try to port the remaining settings to the `test` task of the `java` plugin.

Comment: thanks, I only kept useJUnitPlatform() in the test task, all other references to this plugin were removed and it works nicely.